# How to verify the following?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $x \in \mbox{Ker}(A)$, then can we prove that $x \in \mbox{Ker}(AB)$, where $A$ and $B$ are matrices of compatible orders and $B$ is invertible?

Comment: It's not true. However, $x\in\ker(A)$ implies $B^{-1}x\in  \ker (AB)$ and $x\in\ker(BA)$.

Answer (score 2):

We can't verify that because it is not true in general. Suppose that$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\text{ and that }B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$Then, if $v=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, then $v\in\ker A$, but $v\notin\ker(AB)$.

Comment: But in my problem the matrix $B$ is invertible.

Comment: @thomus take $B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\1& 0\end{pmatrix}$ instead.

Comment: @thomus I missed that, but I corrected my answer.

Comment: I got it.  As a particular case, if we assume that $B$ is diagonal invertible matrix, then in such case I think the answer is yes.

Comment: @thomus No. Do you want a counterexample?

Comment: Yes, if such examples are there..

Comment: @thomus Take$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix},\ B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}\text{ and }v=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: thank you @ jose

Comment: @thomus If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

$B^{-1}x \in \operatorname{ker}(AB)$ as $(AB)B^{-1}x = A(BB^{-1})(x) = Ax = 0$. José already gave an example where your direct statement fails. We do have that the dimensions of the kernel of $A$ and $AB$ are the same.